# Edit Tkinter element from another function in another class

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Listbox that I want to add lines to using a function that is defined within another class.
I want to use this list box to display errors and act as a console output.
Code goes something like this:

```
class BackEnd:
    def BackendFunction:
        if(a = b):
            GUI.console.insert(END, "A = B") # Try to update the console           

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root): # Initiate all elements for the GUI

        # Console Output
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
        scrollbar.place(x=445, y=420, width=370, height=260)

        console = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        console.place(x=445, y=420, width=370, height=260)

        scrollbar.config(command=console.yview)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I get the error: "GUI" has no attribute "console"

I understand that its because console is defined within a function inside of "GUI" but I am unsure how I can "go within" the function again to update it.

Comment: App class is not defined at all in your snippet. Have you switched names in your [mre]? Under the assumption `App is GUI` and you don't try to call `App.console.insert(END, "A = B")` inside (or before) `GUI.__init__` then just writing `App` lowercase should do the trick, since `app = GUI(root)` is defined in the global namespace.

Comment: @Thingamabobs So sorry, yes I did switch names, updated now.

Comment: well then it is lowercas `GUI` like `gui.console.insert(END, "A = B")`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work :(

Comment: oh yea, sure. You never bound the attribute to the instance. Do `self.console = Listbox(...` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed up your code a bit, as a commenter said you need to make `console` a `GUI` class attribute and also pass a referance to the instantiated `GUI` in the `BackEnd`'s constructor.

This is what the code I worked on looks like.

```
import tkinter as tk

class BackEnd:
    
    def __init__(self, gui):
        self.GUI = gui

    def BackendFunction(self, a, b):
        self.GUI.console.insert(tk.END, f"{a} = {b} is {eval('a==b')}") # Try to update the console  



class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root): # Initiate all elements for the GUI

        # Console Output
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root)
        scrollbar.pack()

        self.console = tk.Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.console.pack()

        scrollbar.config(command=self.console.yview)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = GUI(root)
    back = BackEnd(gui)
    for i in range(20):
        back.BackendFunction(1, i)
    root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps!
Comment if you want some more explanations.

Comment: Why don't you just use `a==b` instead of `eval('a==b')`?

Comment: True I could, but this allows for more flexability since you could add a `operand` parameter to check different operations. Or you could pass your full operation as a sting.